# Get URL in twig

Tags: twig

Need to get the URL in a template.

I have tried using get.request.url and it always returns blank.  I've tried get.request.attributes.get('_route') and it always returns blank.  Since I'm new to twig I'm sure I'm missing something fairly basic and easy.

Comment: Which framework are you using or are you using twig standalone?

Comment: twig standalone; it makes me think that I need to do part of it in php and then use twig but it's not at all clear.

Answer (score 1):

As you are working with `twig` standalone, u'd need to pass the information yourself. You could create a small wrapper class to solve this for you though.

*Request.php*

```
class Request {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function get($key) {
        return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : null;
    }

    public function post($key) {
        return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : null;
    }

    public function url() {
        $http = 'http'.(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 's': '');
        return  $http.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
}
```

And register the class as a global into `twig`:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__.'/../views');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
    $twig->addGlobal('request', new Request());
```

Now you can use your wrapper inside `twig`

```
{{ request.url }}{# output current url #}
{{ request.get('variable') }}{# contents of $_GET['variable'] when set or null #}
{{ request.post('variable') }}{# contents of $_POST['variable'] when set or null #}
```

Comment: Thanks a million!  It is quite helpful to get the URL for my app and there wasn't any information about how to get it done until now!